# Android FDE - Why is key stored in RAM at all?

Tags: android, disk-encryption

As far as I understand, the device's `/data` partition remains decrypted once an encrypted devices has been unlocked during boot up. Why does Android have to keep encryption keys within RAM if no "live" decryption / encryption is actually happening?

Comment: Even if it worked the way you imagined, you'd still need the key in RAM to encrypt the data and save it, right? Or do you imagine the user would get prompted for password at every shutdown (or lose data otherwise)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you understand the concept wrong. The encrypted partition will not be fully decrypted on mounting, then stored somewhere on the device and then encrypted again (to save the changes) whenever the partition gets unmounted. Instead the key is known the the kernel (i.e. it is in RAM) and it can thus decrypt and encrypt data on the fly.

Comment: if the partition was fully un-encrypted and you lost power the un-encrypted files would not be protected, every write uses the in ram key to encrypt and save the file.

Comment: @Pieter: Not to mention the notorious difficulty of securely erasing *anything* on an SSD.  If it wasn't encrypted when it hit the drive, it's effectively compromised for good.